# Mathematical Induction for a C++ loop

Tags: induction, recursion

```
unsigned long long int H(unsigned long long int n){
    unsigned long long int res = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        res += n / i;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I'm trying to convert this simple loop into a mathematical equation, I did a couple of attempts based on the example given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) and failed miserably.

What I reached so far: `H(n) = (n / 1) + (n / 2) ... (n / n-1)`

So if `n = 3` then `H(3) = 3 + 3/2 = 5` (Because the result of each division is always an int).

and at `n = 5` the result would be `H(5) = 5 + 5/2 + 5/3 + 5/4 = 10`.

But I can't convert this into an equation..
A little explanation would really be appreciated so I can convert other loops later on.

Comment: What type is `n`? If it's an integer type, you get integer division, so $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \biggl\lfloor \frac{n}{i}\biggr\rfloor.$$

Comment: Actually, in C++, isn't `n/i'` always an int, if n i are ints?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually they both are, so yes the result is an int. That makes my examples wrong.. I'll correct them.

Comment: Since we're dealing with non-negative integers, the division truncates, so `3/2` gives `1`, not `2`.

Comment: [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function)

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't add the full code, forgot `res` was initialized to `1`, just updated it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively asking for a closed form of the series:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{i}$

As far as I know, there is no "solution" to this problem; the series itself diverges as $n$ tends to infinity...

Comment: It'd be commonly denoted by $n H_{n-1}$. (Though see the comments about integer division on the original question.)

Answer (score 0):

The value of res is $n$ times the $n-1$st harmonic number. See
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number
for alternative formulas.